# How to login via cookie using mechanize python

Tags: python-2.7

please help me how to login with facebook using mechanize module with cookie
on python2.7 beacause i'am login with generate facebook access token using mechanize module without cookie my account got checkpoint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Mechanize log into Facebook cookie error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309937/python-mechanize-log-into-facebook-cookie-error)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31716124/10362396) answer